# Determining value of n where an algorithm is better

Tags: algorithm

Algorithm A uses 10n log n operations and Algorithm B uses n<sup>2</sup>  operations.
Determine the value of n0 such that A is better than B for n <= n0.

I don't exactly understand what they mean. I figured n is 10 because at that time A(10)=100 and B(10)=100.
Is this correct?

Comment: That is assuming the log is base 10, you need to check this as it may be base 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes kind of, the answer is 11 or more

Comment: Thank you for your comment mate. I understand the 11, but if they say <= (smaller of equal to), isn't it 10? Even though 11 is still the better right. I thought the n0 means least.

Comment: When n is 10 they are of equal complexity